# JavaFX How to change ProgreesIndicator "Done" message at the end of progress

Tags: javafx, progress-indicator

**Is there any reliable way to change text or set System Locale for controls.properties?**

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
    progressIndicator.progressProperty().addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        if (newValue.doubleValue() >= 1.0) {
            Text doneText = (Text) progressBar.lookup(".percentage");
            doneText.setText("Finished");
        }
    });
```